# Can you not subtract an array from another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Cant figure out the problem here, `a = lengde(OC-OB)`. Can you not subtract an array from another array? Code from school book so i know its bad.

```
from math import sqrt
from numpy import array

# Kordinater hjørner

#A
ax = input("X kordinat A: ")
ay = input("Y kordinat A: ")
#B
bx = input("X kordinat B: ")
by = input("Y kordinat B: ")
#C
cx = input("X kordinat C: ")
cy = input("Y kordinat C: ")

# Lager vektorer
OA = array([ax, ay])
OB = array([bx, by])
OC = array([cx, cy])

def lengde(v):
    return sqrt(v[0]**2 + v[1]**2)

# Regne ut sidelengder trekant
a = lengde(OC-OB)
b = lengde(OA-OC)
c = lengde(OB-OA)

# Omkrets
S = a+b+c

# Radius og sentrum
s = (a*OA + b*OB + c*OC)/S
r = sqrt((S-2*a)*(S-2*b)*(S-2*c)/S)/2

print("Radius = " + r)
print("Sentrum = " + s)
```

Comment: Your arrays contain strings, not numbers. You can't do arithmetic on strings.

Comment: What was the error message?